# Could a prime of the form $91^n+8264$ exist?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Upto $n=20.000$, I did not find a prime of the form $91^n+8264$. Is there some mathematical reason why this type of prime cannot exist?

Comment: Did you check the factors of the numbers with $n=0,1,2,...$? Any factors repeating? If so, you are on your way. If not, then it may be more challenging :-)

Answer (score 12):

For any $n\geq 0$, $91^n$ will always end in a $1$, so $91^n + 8264$ will always end in a $5$.

Comment: Actually, for $n \geq 0$.

Comment: @AlexSilva You're right, although that's sortof just random happenstance.

Answer (score 4):

$$91^n+8264 = (3\times 30+1)^n + (3\times 2754+2)$$

Taking this (mod 3) gives 0 for all $n\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

By below $91^n + 8264$ is divisible by $\gcd(90,8265)=15\,$ for all $\,n\ge 0$

**Theorem** $ $  For all $\, n\ge 0\!:\ c\mid a^n+b\, \iff\, c\mid a-1,b+1\iff c\mid\gcd(a-1,b+1)$

**Proof** $\ (\Rightarrow)\ \ $ For $\, n = 0,1\,$ we have $\,c\mid 1+b,a+b\,$ so $\,c\,$ divides their difference $\, a-1.$

$(\Leftarrow)\ \ \ a^n + b = a^n-1 + b+1\,$  and $\,c\mid a-1\mid a^n-1\,$ for all $n\ge 0$